# Attribute Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating an image tag using the following code..

```
var a = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<img src="/hello" alt="Promised">', "text/xml");
for(var b in a){
    alert('b is: ' + b + '.Value is: ' + a[b]);
}
```

In the above code, I am not able to get the value of alt attribute of image. Why is alt not displayed in the for loop?

I know we can get the attribute as:

```
var a = document.getELementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
```

But why is it not working inside of for loop?

Comment: Why are you using a loop if your code only returns a single element?

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson He's trying to loop over that element's attributes, not over a collection of elements.

Comment: I am using it to get all the attribute values of img tag..Here b is attribute name and a[b] is attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't help that you are parsing it as XML, yet it isn't valid XML (no closing tag).  Try this:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(a)
```

You get this parser error:

```
<img src="/hello" alt="Promised">
    <parsererror xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
        <h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3>
        <div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 34: Extra content at the end of the document
        </div>
        <h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3>
    </parsererror>
</img>
```

If you fix the XML (closing tag) and repeat, you get:

```
var a = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<img src="/hello" alt="Promised"></img>', "text/xml");
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(a)
```

Results in:

```
<img src="/hello" alt="Promised"/>
```

If you parse it as HTML instead:

```
var a = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<img src="/hello" alt="Promised">', "text/html");
```

You'll get this instead:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="/hello" alt="Promised" />
    </body>
</html>
```

To loop over the element's attributes, you need to fix your loop:

```
var elem = a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
    var attrib = elem.attributes[i];
    if (attrib.specified) {
        console.log('b is: ' + attrib.name + '.  Value is: ' + attrib.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer.. How can I get alt value inside of for loop?